# Will [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5] line usage cause App to be reject by Apple Verification?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I had used `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5]` in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` of `AppDelegate.m`. To increase the 'Splash screen display time' sleepForTimeInterval method were used. Will this line usage cause App to be reject by Apple Verification ? I gone through following link for "App Rejections"

```
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/
```

Can anyone help to make sure this method never affect App Publish ? Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it!  If you want a splash screen to display for some period of time, create a view controller whose view looks exactly like your splash screen.  Display that view controller at launch and leave it there as long as you like.  Putting the main thread to sleep is a recipe for disaster.

That said, why are you planning to torture your users?

Answer (score 1):

Your app may not get rejected, but it definitely will be a bad user experience.

The purpose of the splash screen give the impression to the user that the app is responsive. The splash screen is shown as soon as the user taps the icon, to give the feedback that the app is loading. This time should only be used to load the essential components required to start your app.

iOS does have some limits on how much time is allowed for your app to load. If it does not respond in time, the OS will kill the app.

Why would you want to add another 5 seconds to the launch time?